# Creating an installation zip file

Tags: plugin-development

I'm having trouble trying to produce an installation zip file for a gutenberg block that I've developed.

I'm using `wp-scripts plugin-zip` to create the zip.

In the past, I found that the name specified in the `package.json` must match the name of the main PHP file. i.e. if name = "myplugin", then the main php file should be called `myplugin.php`. I'm using that convention.

When I run the plugin-zip command, I only get the files in the build directory. No PHP files are included.

I also tried using a files section in the `package.json`, something like this:

```
"files": [
    "/build",
    "my-cards.php",
    "my-cards-functions-library.php"
],
```

Again, only the `build` directory is included in the zip file.

Does anyone please have any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the full code in your `package.json`? Also, it'd be helpful to add the `wp-scripts` version you used, and the structure of your directory.

Comment: Hi Tom, 
Thank you for your reply.
I've put my project into bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/bugdens/netmonics-card/src/main/
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm not Tom... But anyway, maybe you can try updating your @wordpress/wp-scripts package, and also NPM, to the current latest releases? Have you tried doing so?

Comment: Hi Sally, Thank you for your reply. Yes, I tried that but good idea. It didn't make any difference I'm afraid.